# How to Disable submit button on form after user click in the submit button angular 6

Tags: button, angular6, submit

This is what I want my button to do . 
I want my button to be disable until the user enter all the values need it in the form.
Once the user enter all the values in the form  the user should be able to click in the submit button. 
Then after the user click in the submit button this button should be disables again

I try this something like this

html

```
 <div class="field is-grouped">
              <p class="control">
              <button class="button is-info"
                  [disabled]="!aFormGroup.dirty || !FormGroup.valid "
                  type="submit"
                   onClick= "this.disabled=true" 
                  >Submit</button>
              </p>
</div
```

ts

```
submit() {..}
```

my button get disable when the user click in the button  but I don't get any results from the api . 
It seem that nothing is send to the api

This works

html

```
 <div class="field is-grouped">
          <p class="control">
          <button class="button is-info"
              [disabled]="!aFormGroup.dirty || !FormGroup.valid "
              type="submit"
              >Submit</button>
          </p>
```

ts

```
 submit() {..}
```

but my button is not disable after the user click on it

Answer (score 0):

You can define a public boolean field in the component and bind the value to the [disabled] attribute in the html.

```
[disabled]="!aFormGroup.dirty || !aFormGroup.valid || isDisabled"
```

and set the value to true in the submit method.

Here is a little example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygdag8